# How to convert lists to json in model in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a model through which I receive data from the server. I do everything through the fromJson method, as it should be, but I ran into a problem that I can’t convert some data back to toJson. I have lists that I get but how to convert them back to json with this there are difficulties. Can you tell me how to correctly write the data in the toJson() method so that they are converted?

```
 class PublicChargingStationModel {
      final int id;
      String name;
      List<AmenitiesModel>? amenities;
      List<ScheduleModel>? schedules;
      List<PublicChargingDeviceModel>? devices;
      List<PhotoModel>? photos;
      String? picture;
      User? user;
    
      PublicChargingStationModel({
        required this.id,
        required this.name,
        this.amenities,
        this.devices,
        this.schedules,
        this.photos,
        this.user,
        this.picture,
      });
    
      factory PublicChargingStationModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
          PublicChargingStationModel(
              id: json['id'],
              name: json['name'],],
              picture: json['pi cture'] != null ? json['picture']['url'] : null,
              amenities: json['amenities'] != null
                  ? List<AmenitiesModel>.from(
                      json['amenities'].map(
                        (item) => AmenitiesModel.fromJson(item),
                      ),
                    ).toList()
                  : null,
              user: json['user'] != null ? User.fromJson(json['user']) : null,
              devices: json['devices'] != null
                  ? List<PublicChargingDeviceModel>.from(
                      json['devices'].map(
                        (item) => PublicChargingDeviceModel.fromJson(item),
                      ),
                    ).toList()
                  : null,
              photos: json['gallery'] != null
                  ? List<PhotoModel>.from(
                      json['gallery'].map(
                        (item) => PhotoModel.fromJson(item),
                      ),
                    ).toList()
                  : null);
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        return {
          'blocked': blocked,
          'latitude': latitude,
          'longitude': longitude,
          'name': name,
          'id': id,
          'isFavorite': isFavorite,
          'public': public,
          'status': status,
          'is_open': isOpen,
          'is_free': isFree,
          'country': country,
          'city': city,
          'address': address,
          'zip': zip,
          'remarks': remarks,
          'manual_order_confirmation': isManualOrderConfirmation,
          'picture': picture,
          'formatted_parking_cost_per_hour': formattedParkingCostPerHour,
          'operator': operator,
          'amenities': amenities,
          'user': user,
          'devices': devices,
          'gallery': photos,
    };

  }
```

Comment: How about using the [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) library rather than hard coding?

Comment: you want to convert list<PublicChargingStationModel> into toJson?

Comment: I want to convert all my sheets to json

Answer (score 0):

You have to map your `List<AmenitiesModel>` to `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` by calling `toJson` of `AmenitiesModel`.

Add this code in your `PublicChargingStationModel` `toJson()`

```
'amenities': amenities?.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList(),
```

Do this same for other lists.

Also, I suggest you to use automatic code generation instead of manually creating fromJson and toJson

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json#use-code-generation-for-medium-to-large-projects

https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable

Comment: How would this work when the API is expecting a date in a specific format?

Comment: I'll try your variant and give you an answer

Answer (score 0):

Let say we have `List` Like this:

```
list<PublicChargingStationModel> _list = [...];
```

you can convert it to json like this:

```
var yourResult = {
   'data': _list.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList()
}
```

Note that before use this in your api try this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

jsonEncode(yourResult);
```

Comment: I'll try your variant and give you an answer